# raise forms.ValidationError not working in custom template form

Tags: django, error-handling, django-forms, django-templates

I have a custom template forms

```
           {% extends 'accounts/registration/base.html' %}

           {% block content %}
           {% load bootstrap3 %}

          <div class="container">
  `        `<h1>Sign Up</h1>
          <form method="POST">
    {{form.non_field_errors}}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="email">
    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="phonenumber">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="name">
    <input type="password" name="password1" value="password1">
    <input type="password" name="password2" value="password2">
    <input type="text" name="alternavite_mobile_number" value="">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn default" value="SignUp">
  </form>
     </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

Here is my views.py file

```
def user_signup(request):
registered =False
if request.POST:
    user_form = UserSignupForm(data=request.POST)
    user_pro_form = UserProfileSignupForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_pro_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()
        user_pro = user_pro_form.save(commit=False)
        user_pro.user = user
        user_pro.save()
        registered = True
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError(user_form.errors,user_pro_form.errors)
else:
    user_form = UserSignupForm()
    user_pro_form = UserProfileSignupForm()

return render(request,'accounts/registration/customer_signup.html')
```

what i am getting

```
    ValidationError at /accounts/signup/
    {'password2': ["Passwords don't match"], 'phonenumber': ['Enter a valid         
    phone number.']}
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
    Django Version: 2.0.1
    Exception Type: ValidationError
    Exception Value:    
    {'password2': ["Passwords don't match"], 'phonenumber': ['Enter a valid         
     phone number.']}
```

This is not raising error in form at instance, but on error page showing that form validation error, can you suggest me how to do it and if another simple way to use custom form template.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def user_signup(request):
    registered =False
    user_form = UserSignupForm()
    user_pro_form = UserProfileSignupForm()
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":

        user_form = UserSignupForm(request.POST)
        user_pro_form = UserProfileSignupForm(request.POST)
        if user_pro_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            user_pro = user_pro_form.save(commit=False)
            user_pro.user = user
            user_pro.save()
            registered = True
            return HttpResponse("Success")
            # return render(request,"success.html")

    context["user_form"] = user_form
    context["user_pro_form"] = user_pro_form

    return render(request,'accounts/registration/customer_signup.html', context)
```

in template

```
{{user_form.email.errors}} 

{{user_form.password.errors}}
```

Comment: yeh ! thanks, it's good, but actually I have another form with up to 20 fields, does I need to add that tags for all of them? can jquery help me out ?

Comment: you can use jquery for frontend validation and backend if you are using ajax to post the data . But here you cannot use jquery for backend validation becuase your are rendering the form through django . and give a tick mark if the answer is userful